# NextJS and Auth0 how to get bearer token for api requests

Tags: next.js, auth0

I don't know how to add bearer token header to my API call in fetcher to recieve data becasue I'm checking JWT token on backend...

Fetcher code:

```
 const fetcher = async () => {
      const response = await fetch(api); //I need to add bearer token headers to this api request or else it's 401 
      const data = await response.json();

    const props = {
        data: data
      };
  return props;
};
```

This is data fetching code

```
    const {data, error} = useSWR("data", fetcher);
    
      if (error) return <div>oops... {error.message}</div>;
      if (data === undefined) return <div>Loading...</div>;
      console.log(accessToken);
      return <div>{data}</div>;
```

I found a piece of code in some article which said I needed to add this:

```
 const {accessToken} = getAccessToken({
    scopes: ["read:shows"], // I don't know what is this scope I just pasted it...
  });
```

But accessToken returns error that it can be retrieved only on server side part...

Answer (score 0):

Install [auth0SDK](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@auth0/nextjs-auth0), also if you like to decode jwt token you need to install [jwt decode lib](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jwt-decode).

```
import { getSession, } from '@auth0/nextjs-auth0';
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
...
//all user data here, with tokens
const session = getSession(req,res)
//bearer token here
const token = session.idToken
//simple token here
const tokenId = session.accessToken,
```

Also, in this auth0SDK you have a lot of hooks/functions you can use!